# How do you use Ansible win_find and fetch to copy a group of files from remote Windows to local cansible controller?

Tags: ansible

What's the right way to copy a group of files from a Windows system to the ansible controller?

I can find the files but I don't know how to reference the registered variable data to locate the path to hand to fetch

```
- win_find: paths="C:\\ADirectory" recurse=no patterns="*.log"
  register: file_to_copy

- name: copy files
  fetch: src="{{ item }}" dest=output
  with_items: files_to_copy.files.path
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to iterate over a list and it's the `files` that is a list in the output of `win_find`, not `path`.

This should work for you:

```
- name: copy files
  fetch: src="{{ item.path }}" dest=output
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```

Comment: I found I had to wrap the with_items in a  {{ }}

Answer (score 0):

This seems to work

```
- name: copy files
  fetch:
    src: "{{ item.path }}"
    dest: output/
    flat: yes
  with_items: "{{ files_to_copy.files }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  - name: Copy files
    win_copy:
      remote_src: yes
      src: "{{ item.path }}"
      dest: \\Xxx\\XXX
    with_items: "{{ files_matched.files }}"  
    become: yes
    become_method: runas
```

Used this to copy matched files across fileshare.